# Crop X-Ray Image to Remove black background

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, crop

I want to remove a background from x-ray to extract actual area. So My original [image: Original Image]
 image looks like left image and I want to crop to look like [image: To be image] image.

A solution with Python and Open-CV is appreciated.

There are multiple files and so we don't know the height and width to. Crop in advance. So it needs to be computed.

Comment: Try running Numpy's `np.sum(axis=0)` to sum the pixels in each column... or looking at the many other, similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Blacken the bottom two white rows
- Find where all white pixels are in the image
- Get the bounds of those pixels
- Crop the image at the bounds
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('xray_chest.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold 
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
hh, ww = thresh.shape

# make bottom 2 rows black where they are white the full width of the image
thresh[hh-3:hh, 0:ww] = 0

# get bounds of white pixels
white = np.where(thresh==255)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.min(white[1]), np.min(white[0]), np.max(white[1]), np.max(white[0])
print(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)

# crop the image at the bounds adding back the two blackened rows at the bottom
crop = img[ymin:ymax+3, xmin:xmax]

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('xray_chest_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('xray_chest_crop.jpg', crop)

# display result
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("crop", crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image with bottom two rows blackened:

[image]

Cropped input:

[image]

An alternate method would be to get the external contour of the white region from the thresholded image. Get the bounds of the contour. Then crop to those bounds.